# accessing a shared pointer with a structure

Tags: c++

This is the struct for my code I am trying to get into leftChild in a function.

```
struct Branch {

        shared_ptr<Node> leftChild; 
        shared_ptr<Node> middleChild; 
        shared_ptr<Node> rightChild; 


        int leftMax;
        int rightMax;

        Branch(shared_ptr<Node> left, shared_ptr<Node> middle): leftChild(left), middleChild(middle) {};
    };
```

my Function accepts this

```
Tval find_helper(Tkey k, shared_ptr<Node>& node)
```

I first use it here

```
find_helper(key, root); //though I believe this is wrong
```

and then I use it again recursively like so

```
find_helper(k, node->branch->rightChild); //also most likely wrong
```

I get the error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘TwoThreeTree::Branch’
                find_helper(k, node->branch->rightChild);

what am I doing wrong in my code

EDIT (node code):

this was given to me like this

```
struct Node;
```

then using a tagged union for this:

```
struct Node {
        enum {BRANCH_TAG, LEAF_TAG} tag;
        union {
            Branch branch;
            Leaf leaf;
        };

        Node(shared_ptr<Node> inLeft, shared_ptr<Node> inMiddle) : tag(BRANCH_TAG), branch(Branch(inLeft, inMiddle)) {};
        Node(Tkey k, Tval v) : tag(LEAF_TAG), leaf(Leaf(k, v)) {};
        ~Node() {
            switch (tag) {
                case BRANCH_TAG:
                    branch.~Branch();
                    break;
                case LEAF_TAG:
                    leaf.~Leaf();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the . operator not the -> operator as your function takes in a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: I changed my code with that but I get that branch is not a member of Node

Comment: You'd need to post the node code for me to be sure,but you have probably forgotten to put a branch field in node.

Comment: Your union needs a name and the branch can be accessed through union_name.branch.See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union for more details.

Comment: that worked! but how does it know to look inside of node for union_name.branch

Comment: In finder_helper you are telling the compiler that it is looking at a node that should contain a union called union_name with an element called branch using the . operator. Hope this helps.